# Guzzle: How to save cookies to use on another php file

Tags: php, guzzle

I used Guzzle lib for my project.

I use guzzle to log in to a website (**domain.com/login.php**) and then I can get another (**domain.com/post.php**) as a logged in user.

The question is "How I can use cookies to load (**domain.com/post.php**) many requests as I want without log in the website again?"

My mine is something like that:

```
login = check cookies saved

if ( login ) then get domain.com/post.php
else 
    log in again, then get domain.com/post.php
```

Many thanks.

Comment: You can go with SESSIONS

Comment: Hello, can you explain more? I'm new

Comment: Session is a kind of cookie but it will be stored in  server only. In PHP you need to start session by adding this line at the beginning for your script.

`session_start();`

Session is a Key-Value storage you can store and retrive data like,

`$_SESSION["current_user"] = "user-id";`

`echo "current user id is ".$_SESSION["current_user"];`

Watch this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqimG7wnXnc

Answer (score 0):

Simply Like,

[PHP Sessions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)
[PHP Cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp)

**Login.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(login_success){

        $_SESSION["active_user"] = "user-ID or Token";

    }else{

        //show login error

    }

?>
```

**Post.php**

```
   <?php
        session_start();

        if($_SESSION['active_user']){

            // Check ID or Token to validate User

        }else{

            // redirect to login page

        }

    ?>
```